# How to copy subdirectories to another folder using names that match text file in python

Tags: python, file, directory, path, copy

I have a directory that contains subdirectories where each subdirectory contains multiple files. I have a text file that contains subdirectories names. I need to match the subdirectories names and copy only those subdirectories to another folder whose name occur in text file.

My text file contains the subdirectory names. I want to keep the hierarchy to my destination folder.

**the hierarchy of directory to be copied is as follows.**

```
Directory    
     subdir1
          file1
          file2    
     subdir2
          file1
          file2
```

**I tried this code but it doesn't work.**

```
import os
import shutil

def main():
    destination = "path/to/destination_folder"
    source = "path_to_source_folder_containing_subdirectories_each_contains_files"

    with open("list.txt", "r") as lines: 
        filenames_to_copy = set(line.rstrip() for line in lines)

    for filename in filenames_to_copy:
        source_path = os.path.join(source, filename)
        if os.path.exists(source_path):
            print("copying {} to {}".format(source_path, destination))
            shutil.copy(source_path, destination)
```

Comment: What does the text file look like? What went wrong?

Comment: text file simply contains names like n02672831
n02691156
n02219486
n02419796
n07739125

in each line separately.this code is not copying anything

Comment: Put that into the question. So, do those names include subdirectory paths? You seem to assume that with `os.path.join(source, filename)`. Or do you want to scan the source tree looking for files with those names? Do you want to keep the subdirectory structure at the destination?

Comment: yes these names are folders that contains multiple files each. and yes i want to keep the hierarchy to the destination as well

Comment: Maybe its just `shutil.copytree` instead of `copy`.

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: You could `print(sourcepath, destination)` before the copy. And what error? If you get the source and destination dirs right, it should work. You may need the `dirs_exist_ok=True` param, depending on whether that's okay for you.